# How do you parallelize RDD / DataFrame creation in Spark?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a spark job that looks like following:

```
def loadTable1() {
  val table1 = sqlContext.jsonFile(s"s3://textfiledirectory/")
  table1.cache().registerTempTable("table1")
}  

def loadTable2() {
  val table2 = sqlContext.jsonFile(s"s3://testfiledirectory2/")
  table2.cache().registerTempTable("table2")
} 


def loadAllTables() {
  loadTable1()
  loadTable2()
}

loadAllTables()
```

How do I parallelize this Spark job so that both tables are created at the same time?

Comment: You've posted this to the `user@spark` mailing list too. If someone wants to read the discussion, the subject is _"Parallelizing multiple RDD / DataFrame creation in Spark"_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to parallelize it. The RDD/DF creation operations don't do anything. These data structures are *lazy*, so any actual calculation will only happen when you start using them. And when a Spark calculation does happen, it will be automatically parallelized (partition-by-partition). Spark will distribute the work across the executors. So you would not generally gain anything by introducing further parallelism.

Comment: This answer is sort of true, however since we are in Spark SQL land things get a little bit different. Dataframe creation & registration operations actually do involve some work, especially with json or similar structures where Spark SQL needs to scan some of the rows to determine the schema instead of just reading the schema from the header. If we look in Catalog.scala we can see that register a table involves looking up the plan and this forces some analysis. We verify this by creating a Dataframe  which doesn't exists and seeing that it fails (which means the evaluation wasn't fully lazy).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Holden! I don't use DataFrames, so I didn't know what goes into their creation. Still, the creation must be very cheap compared to the processing — I don't think much can be gained by parallelizing.

Comment: An interesting use case would be if this were perm tables, not temp tables, for example in parquet format with append mode. In that case it's not lazy at all, because you might be materializing a lot of tables as part of ETL process. I'm trying to do something like that. I get the point about each "loadtable" being parallelized anyway, but if each table is not huge, then the registerTempTable is not going to create a lot of workers, so parallelizing a lot of loads that are each individually serial (or minimally parallel) could be a better use of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use Futures!

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

def loadAllTables() {
  Future { loadTable1() }
  Future { loadTable2() }
}
```

Comment: i wish we were using `scala` and its basis of the underlying [multi-threaded] `jvm`.  It's under-appreciated how much is lost in `python`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with standard scala threading mechanism. Personally I'd like to do a list of pairs with path & table name and then parallel map over that. You could also look at futures or standard threads.

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to Spark, which runs on multiple nodes.

Comment: Hi Paul, this actually does apply since registering the tables can only be done in the driver program.

Comment: No, it doesn't. See the other answer about laziness.

Comment: I added a comment to the other answer explaining that while RDD creating is completely lazy, since we are talking about Dataframes (especially json data frames) the eveluation isn't completely lazy. You can verify this by trying to create a json Dataframe from a file which doesn't exist and notice that it fails immediately, unlike with a regular RDD where it is fully lazy and will not fail until we perform an action on it. Dataframes + lazyness are a bit different than regular RDDs.

Comment: Still  seems clear that running it in separate threads gains you nothing much

Comment: It's true there isn't a big improvement, but with registering lots of Json files as tables you could see something meaningful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82751/discussion-between-holden-and-paul).

Comment: The OP has two tables! You're reaching :) (and sorry, it's late here, no chat)

Comment: Sure, its likely this won't have big impact for two tables - but for all we know they are large json tables. Its also the correct answer in case future people searching for how to parallelize table creation come here. I could add a note that most often you won't need to do this if that would make the answer better in your opinion?

Comment: It still seems not an answer to the question. It doesn't parallelize the construction of the table, just the initialisation, as I understand it. But maybe we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: It palatalizes the Dataframe creation (which, for json involves looking at the data). If you want to do this over chat we could walk through some examples together, but it seems like agreeing to disagree might be the simpler option.

Comment: So, the right answer to speed it up is to use one of the JSON readers that specifies the schema and avoids that step

Comment: That only works if you know the schema in advance, which isn't always the case.

Comment: Sure. But if I was concerned about speed, I think I'd try hard to find out (and I suspect it is nearly always the case. What's the chance of having access to a large data set - i.e. needs Spark and performance is an issue, and knowing how to process it, without knowing the format of that data?)

Comment: While OP's example is not it, I agree there are legitimate cases where you want to parallelize RDD creation. Our code has a bunch of RDDs inside Futures.